# State not defined (reactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm bulding App with React Redux.

This is my reducer:

```
import { INCOME_LIST } from '../actionTypes'

import Immutable from 'immutable'

const initialUserState = {
  list: [{
                    id: 1,
                    label: 'List item 1'
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    label: 'List item 2'
                }]
}

const listReducer = function(state = [initialUserState], action) {
  switch(action.type) {
  case 'INCOME_LIST': 
         return Object.assign({}, state, { list: action.data });

  default: return state;
  }

}

export default listReducer
```

This is my Component:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import { Link, browserHistory } from 'react-router'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import axios from 'axios'

class Income extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }
    }

render() {
 console.log(this.props.items)
        return (
            <div>
                test
            </div>
        )
    }

}

const mapStateToProps = function(store) {
  return {
   items: state.list
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Income);
```

Console says that: 'undefined'
Why console.log(this.props.items) get undifined?
How to right way to get a state from reducer? May be mistake there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three things I can see,

Firstly in `mapStateToProps` function you are defining the variable as store and using it as state. Change it to this

```
const mapStateToProps = function(state) {
  return {
   items: state.list
  };
}
```

Also after the constructor you have an extra `}` thats the reason you get an error when you place you `console.log()` in the `render()` function.

Also in your reducer you the way your are defining the initial state makes it an array. You should correct that like `state='initialUserState`

Complete code

**Reducer**

```
import { INCOME_LIST } from '../actionTypes'

import Immutable from 'immutable'

const initialUserState = {
  list: [{
                    id: 1,
                    label: 'List item 1'
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    label: 'List item 2'
                }]
}

const listReducer = function(state = initialUserState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
  case 'INCOME_LIST': 
         return Object.assign({}, state, { list: action.data });

  default: return state;
  }

}

export default listReducer;
```

**Component**

```
class Income extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }


render() {
 console.log(this.props.items)
        return (
            <div>
                test
            </div>
        )
    }

}

const mapStateToProps = function(state) {
  return {
   items: state.list
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Income);
```

Comment: do this but in console I get Undefined..... Why I can't get state form my reducer?

Comment: Try and console.log(state.list) inside the mapStateToProps function and see if it logs anything

Comment: Do that `const mapStateToProps = function(state) {
  return {
   items: state.list
    
  };
console.log(state.list)
}` nothing happens

Comment: You have to log before the return statement

Comment: In you reducer you should assign initialstate like `state=initialUserState` change that and it should work

Comment: not helps.... do that `const listReducer = function(state = initialUserState, action)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133748/discussion-between-shubham-khatri-and--).

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is named `store`, but you refer to it as `state`.
Try:

```
const mapStateToProps = function(state) {
  return {
   items: state.list
  };
}
```

Comment: yes, you a right. Where I can make сonsole.log(items); for examle. In wich part code? because I try do it in render function and getting error. Sorry I'm new in react

Comment: Whatever returns from `mapStateToProps` is mapped to the component's props. Try `console.log(this.props.items)`.

Comment: In wich part of code I can Paste it? because if I paste in render. I get error

Comment: ge undefined if, paste in render ((